# Twitter not getting the access token and access token secret Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm implementing twitter tweet message in my Android app. I'm able to implement Twitter log in but I guess I'm not able to save the access token after logging in, because when I tweet a message it doesn't appear to my twitter wall. I also try to toast the access token and access toke secret but it is both blank.

Here is my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Intent intent;

    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "hide key";
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "hide key";

    // Preference Constants
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

    // Twitter oauth urls
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

    // Login button
    Button btnLoginTwitter;
    // Update status button
    Button btnUpdateStatus;
    // Logout button
    Button btnLogoutTwitter;
    // EditText for update
    EditText txtUpdate;
    // lbl update
    TextView lblUpdate;
    TextView lblUserName;

    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Twitter
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;

    // Shared Preferences
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    // Internet Connection detector
    private ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();






    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 


        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Check if twitter keys are set
        if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens", "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // All UI elements
        btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
        btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
        btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
        txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
        lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
        lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

        // Shared Preferences
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);


        btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Call login twitter function
                loginToTwitter();

            }
        }); 

        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                // oAuth verifier
                String verifier = uri
                        .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                try {
                    // Get the access token
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                            requestToken, verifier);

                    // Shared Preferences
                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                    // After getting access token, access token secret
                    // store them in application preferences
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                            accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    // Store login status - true
                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                    e.commit(); // save changes

                    Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                    // Hide login button
                    btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // Show Update Twitter
                    lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // Getting user details from twitter
                    // For now i am getting his name only
                    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                    User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                    String username = user.getName();

                    // Displaying in xml ui
                    lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Check log for login errors
                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }


        btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call update status function
                // Get the status from EditText
                String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

                sendToTwitter(status);


            }
        });


    }




    private void loginToTwitter() {
        // Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitter4j.conf.Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // user already logged into twitter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
     * fetched from Shared Preferences
     * */
    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
        // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }







    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Places JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
            String status = args[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                // Access Token
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

                // Update status
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
         * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
         * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    // Clearing EditText field
                    txtUpdate.setText("");
                }
            });
        }

    }


    public static void sendToTwitter(String tweet) {
         String access_token1 = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
         String access_token_secret1 = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("8yTg3E1eHq6YF6l6stS4tQ")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("6spBb7gxsuUMfv50CWSjMZLVhHUEoLXxg97txoon45w")
          .setOAuthAccessToken(access_token1)
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(access_token_secret1);

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter t = tf.getInstance();

        try {
        t.updateStatus(tweet);
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone point what is wrong or missing on my codes? It doesn't throw any error btw.

Comment: this is the tutorial that I followed. But its not working when posting tweet.

Comment: Hey it's like my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648159/android-connection-with-twitter-get-null-answer-from-twitter)  Try to use the getOAuthAccessToken without verifier.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this ...

```
    private TwitterSession mSession;
    private AccessToken mAccessToken;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer mHttpOauthConsumer;
    private OAuthProvider mHttpOauthprovider;
    private String mConsumerKey;
    private String mSecretKey;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;
    private TwDialogListener mListener;
    private Activity context;

    public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "twitterapp://connect";
    private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
    private static final String TWITTER_AUTHORZE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
    private static final String TWITTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    public static final String MESSAGE = "There is lot more to come, Subscribe to http://....";

    public TwitterApp(Activity context, String consumerKey, String secretKey) {
        Log.d("tag", consumerKey + ";" + secretKey);
        this.context = context;

        mTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        mSession = new TwitterSession(context);
        mProgressDlg = new ProgressDialog(context);



        mConsumerKey = consumerKey;
        mSecretKey = secretKey;

        mHttpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey,
                mSecretKey);

        String request_url = TWITTER_REQUEST_URL;
        String access_token_url = TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL;
        String authorize_url = TWITTER_AUTHORZE_URL;

        mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(request_url,
                access_token_url, authorize_url);
        mAccessToken = mSession.getAccessToken();
        Log.d("tag", "Access_Token: " + mAccessToken);
        configureToken();
    }

    public void setListener(TwDialogListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void configureToken() {
        if (mAccessToken != null) {
            mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mSecretKey);
            mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(mAccessToken);
        }
    }

    public boolean hasAccessToken() {
        return (mAccessToken == null) ? false : true;
    }

    public void resetAccessToken() {
        if (mAccessToken != null) {
            mSession.resetAccessToken();
            mAccessToken = null;
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return mSession.getUsername();
    }

    public void updateStatus(String status) throws Exception {
        try {
            mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            Log.d("Twitter Exception * Update Status * tag", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void authorize() {
        mProgressDlg.setMessage("Initializing...");
        mProgressDlg.show();
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String authUrl = "";
                int what = 1;
                try {
                    authUrl = mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(
                            mHttpOauthConsumer, CALLBACK_URL);
                    what = 0;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Twitter Exception * Authorize * tag", e.getMessage());
                }
                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler
                        .obtainMessage(what, 1, 0, authUrl));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void processToken(String callbackUrl) {
        mProgressDlg.setMessage("Finalizing...");
        mProgressDlg.show();

        final String verifier = getVerifier(callbackUrl);

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int what = 1;

                try {
                    mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer,
                            verifier);
                    mAccessToken = new AccessToken(
                            mHttpOauthConsumer.getToken(),
                            mHttpOauthConsumer.getTokenSecret());
                    configureToken();
                    User user = mTwitter.verifyCredentials();
                    mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, user.getName());

                    what = 0;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private String getVerifier(String callbackUrl) {
        String verifier = "";

        try {
            callbackUrl = callbackUrl.replace("twitterapp", "http");
            URL url = new URL(callbackUrl);
            String query = url.getQuery();
            String array[] = query.split("&");
            for (String parameter : array) {
                String v[] = parameter.split("=");
                if (URLDecoder.decode(v[0]).equals(
                        oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER)) {
                    verifier = URLDecoder.decode(v[1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {         
        }

        return verifier;
    }

    private void showLoginDialog(String url) {
        final TwDialogListener listener = new TwDialogListener() {

            public void onComplete(String value) {
                processToken(value);
            }

            public void onError(String value) {
                mListener.onError("Failed opening authorization page");
            }
        };
        new TwitterDialog(context, url, listener).show();
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            mProgressDlg.dismiss();

            if (msg.what == 1) {
                if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                    mListener.onError("Error getting request token");
                else
                    mListener.onError("Error getting access token");
            } else {
                if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                    showLoginDialog((String) msg.obj);
                else
                    mListener.onComplete("");
            }
        }
    };

    public interface TwDialogListener {
        public void onComplete(String value);

        public void onError(String value);

    }
}





public class TwitterSession {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    private static Editor editor;

    private static final String TWEET_AUTH_KEY = "auth_key";
    private static final String TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY = "auth_secret_key";
    private static final String TWEET_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String SHARED = "Twitter_Preferences";

    public TwitterSession(Context context) {
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        editor = sharedPref.edit();
    }

    public void storeAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken, String username) {
        editor.putString(TWEET_AUTH_KEY, accessToken.getToken());
        editor.putString(TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
        editor.putString(TWEET_USER_NAME, username);

        editor.commit();
    }
  public void resetAccessToken() {
        editor.putString(TWEET_AUTH_KEY, null);
        editor.putString(TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY, null);
        editor.putString(TWEET_USER_NAME, null);

        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return sharedPref.getString(TWEET_USER_NAME, "");
    }

    public AccessToken getAccessToken() {
        String token = sharedPref.getString(TWEET_AUTH_KEY, null);
        String tokenSecret = sharedPref.getString(TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY, null);

        if (token != null && tokenSecret != null)
            return new AccessToken(token, tokenSecret);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```